# Is there a better way of exploding the comma maybe from the last item in the foreach statement?

Tags: php, foreach

I have used the Google visulization plugin for displaying charts, because it is dynamically pulled in from a database I have used the following foreach script to display the results:

```
var chartData = {
dynamic: [
['Date', 'Orders'],
<?php foreach($data['orders-by-date'] as $date => $orderCount): ?>
['<?php echo date('d/m', $date); ?>', <?php echo $orderCount; ?>],
<?php endforeach; ?>
[' ',0] /* Fix for IE8 */
]
};
```

As you can see I have to add a fix in for IE8 as the last one has to have the comma removed or it breaks in IE8.

Is there a better way of exploding the comma maybe from the last item in the foreach statement? My way works but it adds on a blank value to the end of the chart which isn't ideal.

I hope this makes sense!

I tried the following but doesn't seem to work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var chartData = {
dynamic: [
['Date', 'Orders'],
<?php $fCnt = count($data); ?>
<?php foreach($data['orders-by-date'] as $date => $orderCount): ?>
['<?php echo date('d/m', $date); ?>', <?php echo $orderCount; ?>],
<?php ($date != $fCnt - 1 ? ',' : ''); ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
]
};
</script>
```

Comment: Just curious, did you notice suggestions were shown to you while you were elaborating your question, or notice the "Related" section on the right side of this page?

Comment: Don't create JSON manually; create the complete array in PHP, then `echo json_encode($array);`!

Comment: Could you write the final result of your data?

Comment: I did yes, I tried the following:

Answer (score 0):

```
var chartData = {
dynamic: [
['Date', 'Orders'],
<?php 
$last = end($data['orders-by-date']);
foreach($data['orders-by-date'] as $date => $orderCount): ?>
['<?php echo date('d/m', $date); ?>', <?php echo $orderCount; ?>]<?php echo ($date != $last) ? ',' : ''; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
]
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var chartData = {
dynamic: [

<?php
$data    = array();
$data[0] = ['Date', 'Orders'];

foreach($data['orders-by-date'] as $date => $orderCount)
{
$data[]="[".date('d/m', $date).",".$orderCount."]";
}

echo implode(",",$data);

?>
]
};
```